# Comparing two list of complex types and get true or false as result for all the properties of the list

Tags: c#, linq

There are 2 Lists

```cs
List<Test> t1 = new List<Test>()
{
    new Test("TestName", "MyProperty", 50), 
    new Test("TestName2", "MyProperty2", 50)               
 };
 
List<Test2> t2 = new List<Test2>()
{
    new Test2
    {
        NameT2 = "TestName",
        PropertyT2 = "MyProperty",
        ValueT3 = 50
    },
    new Test2
    {  
        NameT2 = "Hector",
        PropertyT2 = "MyProperties",
        ValueT3 = 60
    }    
};
```

How do we compare both lists of different complex types to receive true or false as a response.?

**I tried:**

1. Both the lists will be having 100 columns and more hence a normal Linq query isnt fitting as I have to write and compare all the 100 properties or columns.

2.*'IdaTransaction.POC.DotNetApps.Model.DataModel.Test2' does not contain a definition for 'Name'* is the **Exception** I get.
When I use Intersect

```
 var compareL1 = t1.Intersect(t2,new DynamicComparer());

  public class Test
    {
        public Test(string name, string property, int value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Property = property;
            Value = value;
        }
    
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
       // public Test(string name, string property, int value)
        //{
        //    Name = name;
        //    Property = property;
        //    Value = value;
        //}
    
      

        //public bool Equals(Test? other) => this.Name == other?.Name;
        //public override int GetHashCode() => (Name).GetHashCode();



    }

    public class Test2
    {
        public string NameT2 { get; set; }
        public string PropertyT2 { get; set; }
        public int ValueT3 { get; set; }
        public int AdditionalT4 { get; set; }

    }
   



    public class DynamicComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
    {
        public bool Equals(dynamic x, dynamic y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name && x.Age == y.Age;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(dynamic obj)
        {
            return ((string)obj.Name).GetHashCode() * 31
                + ((int)obj.Age).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this for unit testing? FluentAssertions has support for this kind of thing.

Comment: What have you tried already? What didn't work? https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: You can implement a *comparer*, a class which implements either `IEqualityComparer<Test>` to compare for equality only or `IComparer<Test>` to be able to *order* the items. Then all you should do is to mention the comparer in `Distinct`, `OrderBy` etc.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, looks like OP needs comparison by reflection. PropName by PropName.

Comment: There's one pivotal question and if you answer that everything will follow: when is a Test instance equal to a Test2 instance?

Comment: @Gert Arnold when both the lists have same no. of properties or column and same  values in the properties.

Comment: In your example, all properties are value types. What if you have a reference type? What should happen?

Comment: Then, if that's clear, what's the problem you face trying it?

Comment: @Gert Arnold
I have edited my Question I get an exception that says column name isnt same but then if colun name need not be checked instead the data in that needs to be checked

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know if both lists contain the "same" items and compare all three properties? What prevented you from something like this:

```
bool list1ContainsAllOfList2 = t2.All(x2 => t1
    .Any(x1 => x1.Name == x2.NameT2 && x2.Property == PropertyT2 && x1.Value == x2.ValueT3));
```

If this is not the kind of comparison you need, you have to explain your requirement better and show what you've tried.

Comment: I am looking for something with more than 100 columns or properties so the querry above might expect us to write 100 columns in the Query

Comment: Then write a method that has that boilerplate code. But I'm wondering why your type has 100 properties, that's neither good in code nor in the database(normalization).

Comment: I am trying to get values from Excel Sheet and trying to compare 2 excel sheets through LINQ.

Comment: @SubashreeKrishnan: I'd simply use a library that reads the excel files and loads them into a `DataTable`(i.e.[this](https://blog.conholdate.com/total/convert-excel-to-datatable-in-csharp/)). Then you can compare the tables with [`DataRowComparer.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcomparer.default?view=net-7.0)which simply compares all columns using value-based comparison.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter
Oh ok thanks thats easier .. Thanks